# calling function imported module ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Developing a React JS app that is using a library from a 3rd party to access their API.

importing the library and instantiating a new instance seem to work, however calling a function results in a reference error.

const BimWebSdk = require('bimplus-websdk');

ReferenceError: $ is not defined

```
   8 |  const api = new BimWebSdk.Api(BimWebSdk.createDefaultConfig('stage'));
   9 | 
> 10 |        api.authorize.post(xxxx,xxxxxx, 'XXXXXXXX').done(function......        
     |                      ^
```

the library depends on JQuery, which I installed and included on the html file.
Basically it is an API wrapper , no idea why they have a dependency on JQuery and what they do with it.
I am not using it anywhere. 
Not sure if it the error is even related to JQuery but when I searched for this issue I got alot of results pointing in that direction.

Comment: That just means jQuery isn't loaded: are you sure jQuery is being loaded?

Comment: Managed to get it working by using  window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');